# How to select parent view model in Knockout?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, viewmodel

I using two view models, `mainViewModel` and `filterViewModel` in my page, where `filterViewModel` is instanced by `mainViewModel`

```
function mainViewModel() {
    this.data   = ko.observableArray();
    this.filter = new filterViewModel();
}

function filterViewModel() {
    this.filter = function() {
        // ajax blablabla
    }
}
```

How to can I access my `mainViewModel` from `filterViewModel` for set ajax result, executed by `filterViewModel`, to `data` variable in your parent view model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just pass the parent to the child explicitly for simplicity sake.

```
function mainViewModel() {
    this.data   = ko.observableArray();
    this.filter = new filterViewModel(this);
}

function filterViewModel(parent) {
    // do whatever with the parent
    this.filter = function() {
        // ajax blablabla
    }
}
```

As comments point out that is introducing an unnecessary dependency. So it's better to pass the property you want to use instead of the parent model.

```
function mainViewModel() {
    this.data   = ko.observableArray();
    this.filter = new filterViewModel(this.data);
}

function filterViewModel(data) {
    // do whatever with the data
    this.filter = function() {
        // ajax blablabla
    }
}
```

Or you could use an awesome knockout plugin [knockout-postbox](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox)

```
function mainViewModel() {
    this.data = ko.observableArray()
         .syncWith('parentData');
    this.filter = new filterViewModel();
}

function filterViewModel() {
    this.parentData = ko.observableArray()
        .syncWith('parentData');

    this.filter = function() {
        // ajax blablabla
        // do whatever with this.parentData
    }
}
```

Note that "parentData" could be any unique string that identifies the property of the model of your choice.

Comment: Great! this can solver my problem, but Knockout has not any way by default for this situation?

Comment: Not that I know of. It's plain JS at this point so there isn't much you can do about it (you could look up caller, but that's a bad practice). In the markup on other hand knockout allows to access parent model via $parent reference.

Comment: I would advise against using `$parent` to access a different view model. It greatly limits how and where you can use the child view model.

Comment: Usually passing the parent to the child is overkill and creates an unnecessary dependency. It's cleaner to just pass the callbacks and observables that the child needs from the parent.

Comment: Good call @CrimsonChris! I've updated the answer. Thanks!